# Can a variable is used instead of the numeric response code for verifying response status in karate

Tags: karate

Consider the below karate script:
***Scenario: test API
    * def responseCode  = 200

Given path 'api/v1/testsample/' 

When method POST

Then status responseCode***

here I am trying to make the response code as a variable rather than numerically giving it as 200

but it throws the error 'no step-definition method match found for status responseCode'

Is this possible in karate??